# including script with http displays message 'content cannot be displayed'

Tags: javascript

I am building a website for a football club and they want a live table of the league added. TheFA.com provide a feed to do this. Basically when I add the Javascript link below my page loads with "content cannot be displayed" and I have to accept before content is displayed. Is there a way round this as they don't provide a https link. Other websites use this link and don't have that message showing.

```
<script type="javascript/text" src="http://thefa.com....."></script>
```

Comment: is this your browser message or this message is generated by the script of this website?

Comment: Would saving the .js file and uploading it to your site for local use solve the issue?

Comment: its a browse message.